# Is the Sword Maiden blind?

Tags: goblin-slayer

The Sword Maiden wears a blindfold, which usually indicates blindness.  However, she does not act blind, nor does this [wiki entry](https://goblin-slayer.fandom.com/wiki/Sword_Maiden) say she is blind.

If she's not blind, why does she have a blindfold?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, she is blind. In **Volume 2 Chapter 7** of the light novel, it was indirectly stated that she is. To quote,

> Sword Maiden didn’t answer. **With her blind eyes**, she stared at a person who seemed to her a shadow.

Also, in that same volume at **Chapter 12**, it was revealed how her eyes were blinded.

> She had been shut up in a dark stone chamber, riddled with her own filth and that of her captors, crying piteously…
>   **They had burned both of her eyes with a torch**. That was more than ten years ago now.